# Number built from {1,2,3,4,5} given that all digits must appear, what is the probability that the digit appears twice will appear one after the other

Tags: probability

Build number of digits - 1,2,3,4,5 given that all digits must appear, what is the probability that the digit appears twice will appear one after the other?
what I tried to do is at first find $\Omega$
$\Omega = 5\cdot 5 \cdot4 \cdot 3\cdot2\cdot1$

Now, what should I do? calculate the numbers that dont have digits that appear one after the other and substruct from omega?
Note: this is a 6 digit string.
thanks.

Comment: Is this a $6$ digit string? or can it be longer?

Comment: yes, forgot to mentioned that. I edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total number of $6$ digit strings that satisfy the condition that all numbers appear in the string can be counted as follows

1. Choose the number that appears twice. You can do that in $5$ ways.
2. Now arrange the 6 digits in all possible ways, which are $$\frac{6!}{1!1!1!1!2!}=\frac{6!}{2}=360$$ (think as a letter-word problem).
   So by the multiplication rule, you can build $$5\times360=1800$$ different strings.

Now count the favorable outcomes, i.e. the outcomes where both occurances of the digit that appears twice, apper one next to each other.

1. Choose the number that appears twice. You can do that in $5$ ways.
2. Merge the two same digits in one digit. Now you should count all the ways that you arrange 5 distinct digits (one of them is the doubled one), which are equal to $$5!=120$$
   So by the multiplication rule, you can build $$5\times 120=600$$ strings, that satisfy this condition.

Now, since all strings are equally probable, you have by the classical definition of probability that the required probability is equal to $$\frac{600}{1800}=\frac13$$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- How many ways can you choose two of the positions to have the same digit?
- Are the choices in the previous question equally likely?
- How many of those choices involve adjacent positions?

Comment: I tought that there is 5 positions of two same digits,In addition I have 5 numbers so it $$\frac{5\cdot 5}{600}$$ what do you think?

Comment: No. If your string was three digits chosen from $\{1,2\}$ and both used, I would say the answers to my questions were $3$ and $2$, so a probability of $\frac23$.  See if you can reproduce this.

Comment: I am still dont understand it.